# displaying files and sizes slow command

Tags: python, bash

this command to get all files and sizes

```
find . -type f | xargs -I x du -s x > /tmp/asd
```

is like 1000x slower than this python script

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for f in filenames:
        print(f)
        fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        if os.path.isfile(fp):
            print(os.path.getsize(fp))
```

Am I doing something wrong in the bash script?
The directory structure has something like 5million files

Comment: You xargs invocation is starting a new process for `du` each time. Take a look at `find's` exec argument.

Comment: Something like `find . -type f -exec du -s \{\} +` or `find . -type f -exec du -s \{\} \;` The xargs took around 12 seconds compare to 0.6 seconds to my command on a tree with 20k files.

Comment: @AshharHasan the first one then ; the second also executes the command for each individual input

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for catching that. One possible issue is that the `+` version is limited to the number of args your shell allows. Which is generally less than 5 million.

Comment: @AshharHasan I believe  `find -exec ... +` actually handles that gracefully and splits the argument list into segments of manageable size. I didn't find explicit documentation supporting this but the mention in `man find` that "the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number  of matched files" rather than "there will only be a single invocation" seems to suggest that

Comment: Another possible solution is to use `xarg` with the `-n` argument to reduce the number of new processes getting started.

Comment: it's still slow it does like 368 files/second; the python script does 250000files/second, I'm running this on a SSD

Comment: I'd use `stat --printf='%s\n' file` rather than `du -s file`, that should be closer to what your python script does : read the inode's metadata. `du` does more complex work, especially when using the `-s` option. I wouldn't expect the performance to increase that much though

Comment: still nope, this command is about 281files/s `time find . -type f -exec stat --printf='%n %s\n' {} \; > /tmp/thirdlucky`

Comment: You need to change the `\;` into `+` otherwise you're back to spawning a new process for each matched file, which likely explains why your `stat` attempt was slower than the `du -s` one

Comment: `time find . -type f -exec stat --printf='%n %s\n' {} + > /tmp/fourthlucky` works faster than python; faith in bash restored; thanks @Aaron maybe ad this reply as an answer to put an end to this question

Comment: If your faith in bash is based on its throughput performance I'm afraid it won't last that long ;) I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the following :

```
find . -type f -exec stat --printf='%n %s\n' {} +
```

The main boost in performance comes from avoiding to spawn a new process for each file matched by `find`. This could have been done with `xargs`, but as `find` is perfectly capable of executing commands based on the files it matches we might as well remove yet another process.
With `find` this is done by using `-exec ... +` (and not `-exec ... \;`) which will spawn as few processes as possible (based on the maximum number of arguments supported by your OS).

Moreover we use the more basic `stat` rather than `du` to query the file's size, which is closer to what you did in your python script.

Comment: stat and du are the same speed almost; this `time find . -type f -exec stat --printf='%n %s\n' {} + > /tmp/sixth` is 4% faster than `time find . -type f -exec du -s {} + > /tmp/sixth` . the speedup comes mostly from the `+` trick of chaining arguments and spawning fewer processes

Comment: Given your invocation parameters (simple files, no extra param such as `-h`) I'm not too surprised, both tools must be testing whether the file is a directory, then when they find out it isn't they just read its inode metadata and print it. I'd say 4% is still better than 0%, but even then I wouldn't be surprised if it was caused by the environnment and would vary depending on other process / disk access. Nothing wrong with using `du` if you prefer, I just though `stat` might be more performant in some cases given its relative simplicity

Comment: Why even launching `du` or `stat` when `find` can give you directly the data you want: `find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n'`?

Comment: @zigarn very right, I had forgotten that and it should give a substantial performance increase. That would be worth its own answer, care to post it? Otherwise I can edit my answer

Answer (score 4):

`find` has directly a `-printf` option to display some data on the found files:

> ```
> %p     File's name.
> %s     File's size in bytes.
> %u     File's user name, or numeric user ID if the user has no name.
> %g     File's group name, or numeric group ID if the group has no name.
> ...
> ```

So, a bit further than the excellent @Aaron solution, you can get directly the info you want without launching any other process via `xargs` nor `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%p %s\n'
```

Comment: Oddly enough Aaron's solution is faster with `2m43s` vs `3m09s` this solution on about 2million files. Although this solutions looks cleaner, I'm more interested in speed

Comment: Is it better on second launch, by any chance? (wouldn't solve your problem, but I'm curious)